# Local time representation

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to have my local day name representaion with pandas.
I'm in France , so with this
`df=pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-05'),'value':[1,2,3,4,5]})`
and that : `df.date.dt.strftime('%a')`
and thought i would have

```
0    Lun
1    Mar
2    Mer
3    Jeu
4    Ven
```

but it returns

```
0    Wed
1    Thu
2    Fri
3    Sat
4    Sun
```

i checked my locale (`import locale  locale.getlocale()`) the result is correct ('fr_FR', 'cp1252').
What i should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `locale.getlocale()` it defaults to "getting" locale of category=2 (per the docstring), which is `LC_CTYPE` and applies to "classification and conversion of characters", not datetimes as you need ([read more here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Categories.html) about the different locale categories). In your case, you need to set the specific "TIME" locale to French. Try the following:

```py
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'fr_FR')

df.date.dt.strftime('%a')
```

And then you will get:

```
0    Mer
1    Jeu
2    Ven
3    Sam
4    Dim
```